# Recursive SQL query only returning single reference instead of recursive references

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a DB table

```
id (INT, NOT NULL)  
username (NVARCHAR, NOT NULL)  
holiday_replacement (INT, NULL)
```

The `holiday_replacement` is either `NULL` or it references a value in the `id` field.

Now, it would be trivial to determine for whom a specified `id` was the *holiday_replacement*, but to complicate this query the *holiday_replacement* may be chained.

In simpler terms, a user may have a *holiday_replacement* who themselves has a *holiday_replacement*.

In such a case the query should return a list of all users in this '*holiday replacement graph*'.

Currently I have

```
WITH user_graph AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table_name
    WHERE
        holiday_replacement = @current_user_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        tn.*
    FROM
        table_name tn
        JOIN user_graph ug ON ug.holiday_replacement = tn.id
) 
SELECT
    id
FROM
    user_graph
```

However, this query only returns those users who have *directly* referenced `@current_user_id` as their *holiday_replacement* and doesn't consider any other users who should also be returned on account of this chaining.

For example, if I have the following 3 users:

```
id = 1, username = 'user_1', holiday_replacement = NULL  
id = 2, username = 'user_2', holiday_replacement = 1  
id = 3, username = 'user_3', holiday_replacement = 2
```

then for `@current_user_id` = 1, the query *should* return

```
id
---
 2
 3
```

but presently it only considers that *directly referenced* user and returns

```
id
---
 2
```

I just can't wrap my head around what I need to change. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried taking the `WHERE` outside the CTE?

Comment: you have wrong join in CTE use `ug.id =tn.holiday_replacement` instend of `ug.holiday_replacement = tn.id` in join expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code

```
WITH user_graph AS (
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    holiday_replacement = @current_user_id

UNION ALL

SELECT
    tn.*
FROM
    table_name tn
    JOIN user_graph ug ON ug.id =tn.holiday_replacement 
) 
SELECT
    id FROM
    user_graph
```